# C# equivalent of fread

Tags: c#, c++

I am in the process of converting some C++ code to C#, I am trying to figure out how I could write out and following C++ code in my C# app and have it do the same thing:

```
fread(&Start, 1, 4, ReadMunge); //Read File position
```

I have tried multiple ways such as using FileStream:

```
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("File-0027.AFS"))
        {
            //Read amount of files from offset 4
            fs.Seek(4, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            FileAmount = fs.ReadByte();
            string strNumber = Convert.ToString(FileAmount);
            fileamountStatus.Text = strNumber;

            //Seek to beginning of LBA table
            fs.Seek(8, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            CurrentOffset = fs.Position;

            int numBytesRead = 0;

            while (Loop < FileAmount) //We want this to loop till it reachs our FileAmount number
            {
                Loop = Loop + 1;

                //fread(&Start, 1, 4, ReadMunge); //Read File position
                //Start = fs.ReadByte();
                //Size = fs.ReadByte();
                CurrentOffset = fs.Position;
                int CurrentOffsetINT = unchecked((int)CurrentOffset);

                //Start = fs.Read(bytes,0, 4);
                Start = fs.Read(bytes, CurrentOffsetINT, 4);
                Size = fs.Read(bytes, CurrentOffsetINT, 4);


                Start = fs.ReadByte();


            }
        }
```

The problem I keep running into is that `Start/Size` do not hold the 4 bytes of data that I need.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're reading a binary file, you probably should look into using [BinaryReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.binaryreader.aspx). That way you don't have to worry about converting byte arrays to integers or whatever. You can simply call `reader.ReadInt32`, for example, to read an int.